# Почему метод computed не работает при изменении input.value?

Tags: vue.js

При изменении значений полей в `input.value` в поле `total` ничего не происходит, а по идее должны складываться. Почему нет реактивности и как это исправить?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  numbers: [5,5,0,0],
    totalNumbers: 0
  },
  computed: {
   countAll(){
     return this.numbers.forEach((item) => {
       this.totalNumbers += item;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
tr {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td v-for="item in numbers">
        <input type="text" :value="item">
      </td>
      <td>total <span>{{ totalNumbers }}</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что Вы нигде не используете  метод `countAll` . Чтобы он хоть 1 раз отработал, его нужно где-то использовать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" :value="item">` - этой строкой вы только выводите значение в `input`. Но при изменении значения - массив `numbers` не изменяется.

**1 вариант**

Для этого нужно определить метод, который будет изменять значение текущего `input`.

```
<td v-for="(item, index) in numbers">
  <input type="number" :value="item" @input="update($event, index)" />
</td>
```

```
methods: {
  update(event, index) {
    this.numbers.splice(index, 1, Number(event.target.value))
  }
}
```

**2 вариант**

Либо воспользоваться директивой `v-model` для двунаправленного связывания данных с элементами форм `input`, `textarea` и `select`.

```
<td v-for="(item, index) in numbers">
  <input type="number" v-model.number="numbers[index]" />
</td>
```

Теперь значения в массиве `numbers` будут обновляться при вводе в `input`. А модификатор `.number` у `v-model` будет автоматически приводить значение к типу `Number`. Как видно второй вариант попроще, не нужно определять методы в поле `methods`.

Обратите внимание на `numbers[index]` - просто записать `v-model="item"` не даст никакого эффекта для массива, [состоящего из примитивов](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/530).

---

Так как у вас уже определено вычисляемое свойство `countAll`, то вводить промежуточное свойство `totalNumbers` уже не нужно.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbers: [5, 5, 0, 0]
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      // Воспользуемся методом `reduce`.
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
      return this.numbers.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + Number(current))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td v-for="(item, index) in numbers">
          <input type="number" v-model.number="numbers[index]" />
        </td>
        <td>total <span>{{ total }}</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```