# Срабатывание checked на каждом поле отдельно

Tags: vue.js

В таблице - 4 поля с 3 значениями в каждом: 120*80, 120*100, 120*120 (это размеры в сантиметрах). По задумке можно нажимать 1 или 2 флажка в каждом из 4 полей, НО они должны работать независимо друг от друга. К примеру, в 1-ом поле я ставлю флаг на 120*80, во 2-ом - 120*80 и 120*120, в 3-ем - 120*120, в 4-ом - 120*80.

Сейчас работает: при нажатии на флажок выделяются все флажки вообще.
Надо, чтобы работало так: каждый флажок выделяется и не влияет на поведение других чекбоксов.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  checked: false
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Dimensions,cm</td>
      <td v-for="item in 4" :key="item.id">
        <input type="checkbox" id="eur1" value="0.4" v-model="checked">
        <label for="eur1">120*80</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="eur2" value="0.5" v-model="checked">
        <label for="eur2">120*100</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="eur3" value="0.6" v-model="checked">
        <label for="eur3">120*120</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам же давали [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/990351/256824) на схожий вопрос. `v-model` должна быть своя для каждого поля ввода, включая флажки, радиокнопки и выпадающие списки.

Comment: Пробовал, но почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: Ну как бы 'checkbox' по задумке нужны для выбора 1 или 2 вариантов.

Comment: Дополнил описание. Действительно как-то коряво описал задачу. Прошу прощения. Поможете с решением?

Comment: Да, ячейки. Ну если так интересно, то да. Это калькулятор для расчёта сборных грузов в автоперевозках. Есть одно поле, где указывается количество поддонов, затем уже указываются размеры поддонов (120*80, 120*100, 120*120) и в зависимости от указанного размера идёт расчёт ладометров (120*80 = 0.4 ладометра, 120*100 = 0.5 ладометра, 120*120 = 0.6 ладометра) по формуле: кол-во поддонов * размеры поддонов - и получаем итоговое количество ладометров по текущему заказу. В данном шаблоне 4 заказа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94708/discussion-between-alex-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data () {
        return {
         checked: false,
            dataComp:[{a: false, b: false, c: false}, {a: false, b: false, c: false}, {a: 
                 false, b: false, c: false}],
      }
}
    })
```

```css
table {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Dimensions,cm</td>
      <td v-for="(item, index) in dataComp" :key="index">
        <input type="checkbox" id="eur1" value="0.4" v-model="item.a">
        <label for="eur1">120*80</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="eur2" value="0.5" v-model="item.b">
        <label for="eur2">120*100</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="eur3" value="0.6" v-model="item.c">
        <label for="eur3">120*120</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```